# How to prevent touchpad form disabling when touched in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I am running Windows 10. My laptop has a touchpad, which only shows in the Device Manager as `HID-compliant touchpad` and the driver provider is Microsoft, so I have no idea about the actual manufacturer.

It has a "feature" where certain gestures will turn the touchpad off until it is turned back on by Fn+F5..

In my appearance, "certain gestures" include a sleeve or finger lightly touching it in a  random manner, or facing a Boss monster where no touchpad means instant death.

Given the meagre information that I am able to provide, is there any way to make the touchpad be always active (such that it can never be turned off by sleeve, wrist, or BOss monster encounter)?

Perhaps a registry hack?

Comment: Control Panel, Mouse.   Look there for trackpad settings

Comment: And then what? Even supposing I could find any touchpad settings under mouse, which I can't. I am stuck :-(

Comment: You need to see if your touchpad has 3 party drivers you can use for settings. Not enough in your post to say otherwise,

Comment: As per the question `the driver provider is Microsoft` - which is why I don't hold out much hope. If I knew the manufacturer then I could contact the, ask on their forum or DuckDuckGo the problem. I doubt that I will get any joy, so bossing will be problematic until I shell out a few k for a new laptop in a few years time :-(